# JavaScript / How create a new object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in `node.js`, using `express`:

```
app.post('/printUp', function(req, res) {
    var multipl = new require('./multUploud').printNum(req, res);
})
```

and i have the following in my multUploud.js:

```
var partNum = 0;
module.exports = {
     printNum: function (req, res){
        partNum ++;
        console.log(partNum);
    }
}
```

If I sent two commands of post, I see that `partNum` is 1 in the first iteration, and 2 in the second.

is there any option to create a new instance for every app.post request, so it prints 1 and 1?

Comment: What's the `new` doing there?

Answer (score 2):

Just make `partNum` a property of your object. Your `multUploud.js` should look somewhat like that:

```
module.exports = MultiUpload;

function MultiUpload() {
  this.partNum = 0;
}

MultiUpload.prototype.printNum = function (req, res) {
  this.partNum++;
  console.log(this.partNum);
}
```

Then, in your Express post:

```
app.post('/printUp', function(req, res) {
    var MultiUpload = require('./multUploud');
    var multipl = new MultiUpload();
    multipl.printNum(req, res);
})
```

Comment: and the call to the method is the same?

Comment: Yes, everything else is the same.

Comment: It writes the there is no method printNum  for this object

Comment: Oh, there's a pair of braces missing: `var multipl = new require('./multUploud')().printNum(req, res);`. I updated the answer with a cleaner version of the code.